# Laravel - relationship returns string instead of object (belongsTo)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an issue that when calling a relationship in Laravel, i am getting a string instead of an object.  While another relationship to the same model returns an object as expected.

```
class FdaFoiDev extends BaseModel {

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public $table = 'fda_foidev';

    public function manufacturer()  { return $this->belongsTo('Manufacturer'); }
    public function model()         { return $this->belongsTo('ManufacturerModel'); }

}
```

--

```
class ManufacturerModel extends BaseModel {

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

}
```

--

```
class Manufacturer extends BaseModel {

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

}
```

--

In a controller:

```
$f = FdaFoiDev::find(23);
dd($f-> manufacturer);
```

dumps a string:

```
string 'MEDTRONIC' (length=9) // the manufacturer_name field in the DB (first field after id in the related table)
```

while:

```
$f = FdaFoiDev::find(23);
dd($f-> model);
```

dumps the expected result:

```
object(ManufacturerModel)[1260]
  protected 'guarded' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'validator' => null
  public 'validationErrors' => 
    object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)[1261]
.........
```

---

```
$f = FdaFoiDev::find(23);
dd($f-> manufacturer()); //adding parentntheses
```

Does return an object, however, I'm finding it peculiar that calling two relationships with an almost identical table structure is returning differently formatted results.  I am also using a package that refers to relationships in this way, and id really like to avoid modifying it.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?  Are there any other places that define how relationships are returned?

Comment: do you have `manufacturer` column in your table ?

Comment: Ah, YES... thats it!  This is an imported table and has about 75 fields.  I completely forgot that there was a field called `manufacturer` in `FdaFoiDev` which takes priority over the relationship name.  Thanks!

Comment: make sense, rename your relation or use `$f->manufacturer()->first()`

Comment: @Razor You should add this as an answer and I'd be happy to upvote. I just spent half a day trying to debug my relationship before coming across this question and your comment, and I didn't see it mentioned anywhere in the documentation that you can't have a column in your table with the same name as your relationship - this should be much more clearly spelt out in a framework like Laravel, which relies so much on magic and where it's common for names to follow the same conventions.